# Unity launcher: Tor Browser opens as Firefox icon

Tags: unity, firefox, launcher, icons, tor-browser

I have installed TorBrowser through TorBrowser-Launcher and pinned it to my Unity launcher.

Now whenever I start it, it show up in the launcher as Firefox.
I know that TorBrowser is a modified Firefox version, but I would really like if I could modify the .desktop file or anything to make it visible from the dock which browser is opened.

Is this possible or will the Firefox launcher always react on TorBrowser?

PS: My `usr/share/applications/torbrowser.desktop` file:

```
$  cat /usr/share/applications/torbrowser.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Tor Browser
Comment=Launch the Tor Browser Bundle
Exec=/usr/bin/torbrowser-launcher %u
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/torbrowser80.xpm
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**The problem went away, but I don't know why.**

After torbrowser *upgraded* itself to *version 5.0.2* or maybe even a bit earlier, it lights up its own icon when running instead of the Firefox one.

I am unable to explain the reason for this, as the `torbrowser.desktop` file still is the same as described in my question...

Comment: Possibly, in the newer version, the `WM_CLASS` changed. A pitty you updated it, would be interesting to see if the window was of the same class as `Firefox` (by running `xprop WM_CLASS`, but you probably know that :) )

Comment: No, I don't know unfortunately... But you would have had over two months time for asking me to check this ;-) Is the WM_CLASS set somewhere inside a binary or can this be modified? Because after getting used to it, having Torbrowser appear as normal Firefox in the launcher has not only disadvantages, so swapping those modes would be cool. Not necessary, but cool.

Comment: I know, I missed the post completely earlier. Part of the `WM_CLASS` is the executable's name. You can change it with `xprop`, not sure how. The thing is, if two applications have the same `WM_CLASS`, they can only appear under one icon in the launcher. Possibly (I think probably) that was the case.

Comment: Older tor browser masqueraded as Firefox.  It is its own browser now.  The update applied those changes...

Answer (score 0):

I cannot vouch for the safety (in terms of Tor's purposes and goals) of the next solution, but this is what I did in my own case.

I suppose that you already have tor browser registered as an app in your system, but if you don't than run this command from the directory containing the unpacked stuff, it must be something like:

```
~/tor-browser_en-US
```

And run this command:

```
~/tor-browser_en-US$ ./start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app
```

Then the solution itself. You should have a launcher file `~/.local/share/applications/start-tor-browser.desktop` file. Drag it to your launcher bar.
And in the file itself change the line:

```
Exec=sh -c '"/home/<username>/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/home/<username>/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k
```

to this one (with substitution of the username properly):

```
Exec=/home/<username>/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser
```

That is make it to call the executable directly, not via a shell.

That's it, but I would like to repeat that I'm not sure how these changes affect the abilities of Tor browser. I suppose that nothing harmful was done.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this did not help me. I forgot to say that I did not install torbrowser directly, but torbrowser-launcher! So the .desktop file I have is the one above (see question edit).

Comment: @ByteCommander, sorry, then the only thing I can suggest is to install the browser directly, not the launcher via apt-get ((