# Tor starts as Firefox

Tags: unity, firefox, launcher, icons, tor

the machine is running ubuntu 16.04. Firefox is the standart browser (59.0).

Tor (english, 64 bit) has been installed today from https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en using this as guidiance https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Tor/Installation/#Tor-Browser-Bundle-Webdownload

It is up and running, but in the unity taskbar it shows as a firefox window (started via the icon that was created when extracting to the VirtualBox folder (green globe), as intended). When launching Tor it opens a firefox icon on the taskbar, but also a Tor icon with a pulsating green background. It vanishes as soon as a connection is established. start-tor-browser has been made executable.

After testing on showip.net, both windows have a different IP address. [Tor-Browser appears as Firefox in the Unity Launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769392/tor-browser-appears-as-firefox-in-the-unity-launcher?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) referes to the problem, but the torbrowser.desktop cannot be found in the folder. There is a file called applications.ini in ~/Tor(renamed tor-browser_en-US)/Browser, but it states that the file is not used in the first line. [Unity launcher: Tor Browser opens as Firefox icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642283/unity-launcher-tor-browser-opens-as-firefox-icon?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) also referes to a similar problem, but i have not yet tried the first answer given. Is it safe to try?

So: I click the green globe to open Tor, a window pops up stating that the connection is beeing established, then the Tor browser window shows as a firefox icon in the taskbar (when a normal firefox window is also open, it shows as a second window (small triangle) on the firefox icon. Hope this clarifies.

How can Tor be instucted to open with the Tor-Icon, seperated from Firefox in the launcher to prevent usage of the wrong window?

The Tor launchpad has not worked for me, i get errno 2 (#507) in the terminal log when trying to install (with the progress bar stuck at 0%).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tor is a network connection. It uses a locked down version of Firefox as the browser.

Comment: So there is no way to visually seperate them to keep a better overview?

Comment: you should be able to change the icon for the tor launcher. as far as the browser you can apply different themes

Comment: The icon clicked to start tor is the tor icon (green globe), i would like to see that icon in the launcher as well as soon as the window is opened and the connection esablished, and not the firefox icon.

Comment: Ah you mean in the task bar. I'm not sure if that can be changed as it is firefox ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you drag the Tor Browser Icon from the folder you extracted to to the Desktop, it will create its own Icon in the Taskbar (Launcher) and will coexist with the FF Launchpad, even in FF is running.